# facebook session presists in my app even after logging out of the facebook app

Tags: android, facebook

I have integrated the Facebook SDK in my app using the official facebook connect API. I am able to login to the facebook app via my app and the whole single sign on thing works fine.

The problem is coming when I logout of the installed facebook app, the session still persists in my app and I can still post messages. Logging out of the facebook app does not affect my app. If I go into the manage applications and clear cache of my application then the session is also removed from my app. 
Can anybody help me figure out how logging out of the facebook app should clean the session from my app as well??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just used the Facebook api in one of my projects. It seemed to me, that you have to explicitly log out inside your application, using the logout() in the Facebook class.

I don't think that logging out inside the separate Facebook app will log you out from every single app on the device that uses facebook.

Comment: Buy I thought thats how the single sign on works. You just log in and log out once at the device level.

Comment: @Funkyidol yea, as long as you do it on their official app. Other apps "subscribe" to it's main app, not otherwise.